# (When present) Perform Click Event on 'Login' button of Web Page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, allure

My requirement:

When 'Login' button is present, click on 'Login' button and work on use case.
When 'Login' button is NOT present, work on use case directly (No need to click on 'Login' button)

So, I wrote my @Test as below.

```
@Test
@Parameters({ "baseURL" })
public void settings_Preferences_Method(String baseURL) {
    SoftAssert assertions = new SoftAssert();       
    goTo_Us_PioneerHomePage(baseURL);
    **goTo_Us_Login(assertions);**
    goTo_Us_Settings("expectedText");
    goTo_Us_Signout(assertions);
    assertions.assertAll();
}
```

---

```
@Step("Login")
public void goTo_Us_Login(SoftAssert assertions) {  
**int elementPresent = isElementPresent(By.xpath((loginXpath)));**
if (elementPresent>0) {    
    writeText(By.xpath(emailAddressXpath),"uat106@gmail.com");
    writeText(By.xpath(passwordXpath),"test$");
    click(By.xpath(signinXpath));
    Assert.assertEquals(readText(By.xpath(v_DashboardXpath)), "expected Text", "User is NOT in Login page");    
}       
}
```

---

### Methods used:

```
 public void click(By elementLocation) {    
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementLocation));                                         
        driver.findElement(elementLocation).click();    
}
```

---

```
public String readText(By elementLocation) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(elementLocation));
    return driver.findElement(elementLocation).getText();
}
```

---

```
public void writeText(By elementLocation, String text) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementLocation));
    driver.findElement(elementLocation).sendKeys(text);
}
```

---

```
public int isElementPresent(By by) {
    wait.until(driver -> driver.findElements(by).size() > 0);**- When driver.findElements(by).size() = 0 , Control is getting out of 'isElementPresent' method and then getting out of 'goTo_Us_Login' method and then getting out of 'settings_Preferences_Method' WITHOUT executing '3 lines of code' specified below**
    return driver.findElements(by).size();
}
```

---

### Problem

:

When driver.findElements(by).size() = 0 , Control is getting out of 'isElementPresent' method and then getting out of 'goTo_Us_Login' method and then getting out of 'settings_Preferences_Method' WITHOUT executing '3 lines of code' specified below*

```
 goTo_Us_Settings("expectedText");                         
 goTo_Us_Signout(assertions);                                             
 assertions.assertAll();
```

Above 3 lines of code should be executed irrespective of value in driver.findElements(by).size()

Comment: I would also like to know the solution if there is any! Because until I know its not possible as you are looking for element that is not on the page and you will get error for sure.

Comment: What is inside `isElementPresent` method?

Comment: What is your desired behaviour? DO you want to wait till timeout then return *false* without any exception?

Comment: @mentallurg  - I have formatted my question .Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your `isElementPresent()` method so I'm assuming that's where the issue is. I'm guessing you used a `driver.findElement()` call there (Note the singular) and it throws when the element is not found. Instead use `.findElements()` (plural) and check for an empty list.

```
public static boolean isElementPresent(By locator)
{
    return !driver.findElements(locator).isEmpty();
}
```

Then you would use it like

```
@Step("Click on Login and verify whether User is in Login Page.")
public void goTo_Us_Login(String expectedText) {        
    if (isElementPresent(By.xpath(loginXpath))) {
        click(By.xpath(loginXpath));
        click(By.xpath(continueXpath));
        writeText(By.xpath(emailAddressXpath),"uat106@gmail.com");
        writeText(By.xpath(passwordXpath),"test$");
        click(By.xpath(signinXpath));
        Assert.assertEquals(readText(By.xpath(v_DashboardXpath)), expectedText, "User is NOT in " + getCallingMethodName().replace("goToUa", "").replace("Page", " Page.\n\n"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic to check if logged in or not:

1. Wait presence for one of **Login** or **Any Element On Main Page**
2. If **Login** exist do login

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(d -> d.findElements(By.xpath(loginXpath)).size() > 0 || 
        d.findElements(By.xpath(v_DashboardXpath)).size() > 0);
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(loginXpath)).size() > 0)  {
    // login here
}
```